# Unable to use Grails 3.0.9 version

Tags: grails

I am working on Windows. I am trying to use Grails 3.0.9 version. Previously, I used Grails 2.4.2, everything worked well.

After Downloading and setting windows environment for 3.0.9 of Grails, I typed **'grails help' or 'grails create-app test'** on Windows cmd.

It always tell **'Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter'**

Then I try to use 3.0.8, it told the same error. But if I switch to use 2.4.2, it works normally.

Ps. On Grails 3.0.9, I use jdk1.8.0_65.

What I did wrong or what I missed for setting for a new version of Grails.

Thanks.

Comment: add $GRAILS_HOMR\bin to your environment variables

Answer (score 0):

I Had exactly the same problem. You could try that:
Open a new CMD window and print your variables (PATH, GRAILS_HOME) if set.
Sometimes my variables still referenced my Grails 2.3.7 library and not 3.0.8 which I wanted to use.
That was happening on Windows 10 to me. After a few restarts from CMD all went well. Maybe System variables are somehow cached and not set immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using gvm  on windows, its a tool to install, switch grails very quickly using windows powershell

its now called sdkman http://sdkman.io/

if your installing on mac or or unix like os

https://github.com/flofreud/posh-gvm has a good tutorial on installing for windows

`gvm install grails 3.0.9`  , you can set it as the default by saying yes at the end or

```
gvm use grails 3.0.9
```

`gvm list grails` to see what other versions of grails are available to install.

then type `grails -version` to see what version is installed and test out grails

your `grails create-app` should then work